# IntelliJ IDEA Chrome plugin for live update doesn't reload the page

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, livereload

I am used to work on Angular projects where I can simply save my html/css/js change on VS Code and the page reloads automatically with my change. I tried to install the Intellij plugin for live reload, but it doesn't work the same way: nothing is reloaded.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

I've installed both the plugin in my browser and in the IDE.

Comment: make sure to start the debugger first - Live Edit only works during debug session. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Live+Edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install JetBrains IDE Support chrome extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/related

You also need the LiveEdit plugin for your IDE: go to file -> settings -> plugins -> install jetbrains plugin -> search for "LiveEdit" and install and restart IDE.

Then, from IntelliJ, right click the `.html` file and choose "debug".

This should open a Chrome window or tab in debugging session, and all changes updated automatically in chrome.

More info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html#d163908e138

Comment: Jetbrain's extension is discounted(it stopped working after 2020, chrome 86): https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49212